# Why is evaluation dice loss different than evaluation dice metric?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, semantic-segmentation

I am using following python code for calculating the loss.

```
def dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1.):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)


def dice_coefficient_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred)

model.compile(
    optimizer=opt,
    loss=dice_coefficient_loss,
    metrics=[dice_coefficient],
)
```

My model ends an epoch with this

> 488/487 [==============================] - 823s 2s/step - loss:
>   -0.9217 - dice_coefficient: 0.9217 - val_loss: -0.9367 - val_dice_coefficient: 0.8289

Why are val_loss and val_dice_coefficient different and which one is right one? I believe 0.8289 is the correct but why is there a discrepancy in evaluation loss in all of epochs.

I changed the validation generator with the training one and I still got a difference between the two. I'm using Adam and my model is 3dunet. I have batch norm. I don't use regularisation and no dropouts

Comment: I think it is wrong with validation data. Check that.

Comment: I changed the validation generator with the training one and I still got a difference between the two. I'm using Adam and my model is 3dunet. I have batch norm. I don't use regularisation and no dropout.

Comment: Hi @dark1sider, tried using the function for custom loss & metrics and the results are the same, Can you provide the sample model or at least a reference link to it?